# SQLite Adding a Calculated Column

Tags: sqlite, calculated-columns, alter-table, calculated-field

I have a table named "Combined_Bike_Ride" with the below sample data in SQLite

| started_at | ended_at |
| --- | --- |
| 27/05/2020 10:03 | 27/05/2020 10:16 |
| 25/05/2020 10:47 | 25/05/2020 11:05 |

I want to add a new calculated column "ride_length" where ride_length = (ended_at) - (started_at) in that table.

I used the below sql code but getting a syntax error near AS.

```
ALTER TABLE Combined_Bike_Ride ADD COLUMN ride_length AS (ended_at) - (started_at)
```

Am I missing a date calculation? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: SQLite does not have any date type. You REALLY would do yourself a favor if you keep dates in ISO format, `YYYY-MM-DD hh:nn:ss`. This makes it fairly trivial to cast the string as a date, and do your calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you must change the format of your dates to `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` because this is the only text date format that you can use with SQLite's datetime functions if you want to perform operations such as calculation of time difference.

For this purpose you can use the function `strftime()`.
With `strftime('%s', datetimecolumn)` you get the number of seconds between `1970-01-01 00:00:00` and the value of `datetimecolumn`

The correct syntax to add the new column is this:

```
ALTER TABLE Combined_Bike_Ride 
ADD COLUMN ride_length 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((strftime('%s', ended_at) - strftime('%s', started_at)) / 60)
```

Comment: @bknmz strftime() does not convert dates that don't have the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm to other formats. Change the format of your dates in the table to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This means that I gotta go back to my all csv files , convert date types and import to my db. May be I should have added the calculated columns via excel.

Comment: @bknmz The data type is not important in this case since SQLite does not have a Date or Datetime data type although you can declare it as such. The actual data type should be TEXT. What is important is the format of the date strings.

Comment: @user117529 correct. I edited.